# Can i use promise/a for event handling?

Tags: javascript, promise

I want to turn

```
$(button).on("click",function(e) {
    $.ajax(url, function(data) {
        handle(data);
    });
});
```

into:

```
$(button).on("click")
.then(function(e) {
    return $.ajax(url);
})
.then(function(data) {
    return handle(data);
});
```

But *a promise can only resolve once* while click event will be triggered again and again, that make things impossible.

Any elegant solutions?

Comment: No, promises by definition are resolved only once. What you want is called *Stream*s.

Comment: @Bergi - I've googled javascript streams and haven't found what you are referencing. Do you have any links?

Comment: @Aust: Try again with "*functional reactive programming*" as the buzz-, er, keyword then.

Comment: @Bergi: That did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: I think Bergi's comment is actually the correct answer.  (I've noticed that people frequently put answers in comments - not sure why.)  I have the same question.  Having learned about promises, I happily started writing code using them.  In most cases it works great, but in cases where you have to handle a stream of events, they simply aren't a good fit.  (At least, that's what I've concluded.)

Answer (score 0):

In order to issue the ajax request only once, no matter how many times the button is called, you can reference a single promise. You can call promise methods repeatedly, and they will resolve immediately if the transaction has already completed.

```
var promise;
function sendAjaxRequest() {
     return promise || promise = $.ajax(url);
}

$(button).on("click", function(){
    sendAjaxRequest().then(function(data) {
       handle(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: That was not the question, at least I don't think so.  I think the OP wants to handle EVERY button click.  And I think the answer is that promises are not a good solution for this.  (But someone please correct me if that's wrong.)